# Debugging issue in Sprinboot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, program-entry-point

I am trying to debug my spring boot  application but debugger is getting suspended at run method but my application is working.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Application Started");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

What can I do so debugger moves ahead ?

Answer (score 0):

Check Breakpoints:
Review your breakpoints in your IDE and make sure that you don't have any breakpoints set within the Spring Boot framework or any unwanted breakpoints that might be triggering the suspension.

Disable Breakpoints:
Temporarily disable all breakpoints and try running your application again to see if it runs without the debugger being suspended. If it works fine, you can enable the breakpoints one by one to identify which one is causing the suspension.

Configure Exception Breakpoints:
In some cases, the debugger may suspend at the run method due to an unhandled exception. You can configure your IDE to only stop at caught exceptions rather than suspending on all exceptions. Check your IDE's settings to configure exception breakpoints accordingly.